# Seifert surfaces for knots $6_1, 6_2, 6_3$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, knot-theory, orientation, knot-invariants

I have been trying to calculate the genera of these knots, but the first step in doing so is to convert them into orientable knots by constructing Seifert surfaces for those knots. I started to do this using the algorithm here https://users.math.yale.edu/~ml859/seifert_talk.pdf but the algorithm is not clear in the case of those 3 knots.

I got stuck (I will upload the pictures I got as long as I know how to do this as they are on my phone right know).

**My Questions:**

1. Can anyone mention a more rigorous reference for Constructing Seifert surfaces, knowing that the talk mentioned before refer to Massey "Algebraic topology: an introduction" but I did not find a rigorous algorithm in it.
2. Can anyone show me the shape of this Seifert surfaces?

Thanks!

Comment: The Seifert circles might be nested, leading to nested disks, so to speak.  The genus of the resulting surface is an upper bound for the genus of a knot, and there are some knots where the minimal genus Seifert surface does not arise from Seifert's algorithm for any diagram!

Comment: Some references are Rolfsen's Knots and Links and Lickorish's Introduction to Knot Theory (theorem 2.2). I was also made aware of Prasolov's Intuitive Topology recently, which has some nice pictures.

Comment: @KyleMiller  for your last part in your first comment are you speaking about calculating the lower bound of the genus through half the span of the Alexander polynomail?

Comment: No, I'm not speaking about algebraic invariants.  The "canonical genus" is the minimal genus of all Seifert surfaces that come from Seifert's algorithm, and this might be bigger than the actual minimal genus of a Seifert surface --- a Seifert surface is *any* embedded compact oriented surface whose boundary is the knot, not just those that come from Seifert's algorithm.  I brought it up to point out that Seifert's algorithm does not compute genus, which is what you said you were trying to do (though it does provide upper bounds).

Comment: For example, the canonical genus of a Whitehead double of a trefoil is $3$, but its genus is $1$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633239/does-seiferts-algorithm-produce-seifert-surfaces-with-minimal-genus

Comment: yes, I know that seifert algorithm help me to construct an orientable surface from the given knot ...... correct?@KyleMiller

Comment: Also what is the "smooth 4 genus" I found it for knot $6_{1}$ to be 0 on wikipedia @KyleMiller

Comment: Yes, *an* orientable surface, and by "does not compute genus" I meant in particular that the surface you get might not have minimal genus.  Smooth 4-genus is the minimal genus of a compact oriented surface that is allowed to be smoothly embedded in $B^4$ rather than $S^3=\partial B^4$.  This is also known as smooth slice genus.  A *(smoothly) slice knot* is a knot whose smooth 4-genus is $0$.

Comment: My confusion for $6_{1}$ knot is that I calculated the Alexander polynomial of it and it turns out that its genus is greater than or equal 2 ........ am I correct? If not can you  help me in clarifying this ...... Also, according to what you said in your previous comment, I feel like the smooth genus is the same as the genus I am calculating , correct? @KyleMiller

Comment: The Alexander polynomial of $6_1$ has breadth $2$, so $2/1=1$ is a lower bound for the knot's genus.  Smooth $4$-genus is a lower bound for $3$-genus (a.k.a Seifert genus) -- you gave the example of $6_1$ having a smooth $4$-genus of $0$ but its $3$-genus is $1$. https://www.indiana.edu/~knotinfo/ is useful.

Comment: My Alexander polynomial for $6_{1}$ knot is $t^4 - 5t^3 + 8t^2 -5t +1$ , so its span is 4, so the lower bound of its genus is (1/2 span of its Alexander polynomial) so the lower bound of the genus is equal to 2. Actually I do not understand what you mean by breadth of the Alexander polynomial , could you clarify this please? is your Alexander polynomial different than mine? @KyleMiller

Comment: Do you know a good book for Calculating the Alexander polynomial of a knot as I used only this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwz9GvJk49k&list=PLOROtRhtegr4c1H1JaWN1f6J_q1HdWZOY&index=3  @KyleMiller

Comment: These things about Alexander polynomials should be a new question.  All I can say here is that the Alexander polynomial of $6_1$ is $-2t^2+5t-2$.

Comment: 2/1 = 2  so the minimal genus is 2@KyleMiller

Comment: Is $S^3 = \partial B^4$  correct? @KyleMiller

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you can get a Seifert surface using Seifert's algorithm for $6_1$'s usual diagram:

[image: Getting a Seifert surface for 6_1]

First you choose an orientation of the knot -- either gives the same result.  Then you smooth the crossings in the way that preserves orientations, giving a collection of Seifert circles/circuits (drawn in black).  Thinking of the diagram as sitting in a plane, start with an innermost Seifert circle and attach a disk to it underneath the plane.  Keep taking an innermost circle that has yet to have a disk attached and continue this process.  Then, glue in half-twisted strips at the crossings in the way that follows the knot (drawn in blue).

For $6_1$, there is one disk nested in the other.  The resulting Seifert surface has genus $1$, and since by other reasons $6_1$ is non-trivial (for example, this is a reduced alternating diagram so has the minimal crossing number), its Seifert genus must be exactly $1$.

You can isotope the surface to look like the following, which possibly might illustrate the surface a little better:

[image: The Seifert surface in another form]

For sake of another example, here is $6_2$:

[image: Constructing a Seifert surface for 6_2]

How do we calculate genus?  The genus of a connected surface with exactly one boundary component satisfies the following formula, where $d$ is the number of Seifert circuit disks and $c$ is the number of crossing bands: $d-c+1=2-2g$, hence $g=(1-d+c)/2$.  In this example, we get a Seifert surface with genus $(1-3+6)/2=2$.  According to KnotInfo, this is the genus of $6_2$, but *a priori* we only know that $2$ is an upper bound for the genus.

Comment: Does the orientation of the half twisted strips matters? Because the above mentioned algorithm did not mention anything about that.

Comment: @Intuition Yes, the orientations matter (if you did the wrong orientation, you would get a Seifert surface of a crossing-changed version of the knot).